# Javascript reference error but works when I use a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, applescript, referenceerror

I'm trying to execute some Javascript on a page that's already fully loaded.

To test the javascript, I created a bookmarklet, clicked it while the page was loaded, and it executed properly:

```
javascript:(array.find('value').__showAllRecords(event))
```

I wanted to use this Javascript in an AppleScript I'm writing that sends it to chrome, but for some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: array is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

It only happens when I run my script in my AppleScript editor, not when I use the bookmarklet. Here's my AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "array.find('value').__showAllRecords(event)"
end tell
```

Comment: I am getting array is not defined in the bookmarklet as well. Where have you defined your array?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `array` is created at some point in time after your script executes, since you don't know when you could retry until it does exist:

```js
(function(){
  function trySomething(){
    try{
      array.find('value').__showAllRecords(event);
      console.log("worked, stop trying");
      clearInterval(timer);
    }catch(e){
      console.log("didn't work, try again",e);
    }
  }
  var timer = setInterval(trySomething,1000);
}())

//create the array object some time in the future (not actually an Array type)
//this is not part of your script but would be created by the page
//at some point
setTimeout(
  ()=>window.array={find:x=>({__showAllRecords:x=>x})}
  ,6000
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, applescript does not have access to the non default globals. See the thread https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543437

But there is a workaround, what you can do is set the array as innerHTML of a div and retrieve the value from applescript. So for e.g. this is my div `<div id="test">[1,2,3]</div>`, you can execute

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    execute front window's active tab javascript "console.log(document.getElementById(\"test\").innerHTML)"
end tell
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This may help, but the problem is that I'm trying to execute this on a site that I don't develop for, essentially trying to create a macro, so I'm not sure where the array is even defined. any ideas?

Comment: I see, what I would recommend is then try and get information from the DOM since applescript does not have access to the page variables directly